# Why does my Deep learning application require so much RAM?

Tags: python, memory, deep-learning

I am new to Deep learning. I have learned the Deep learning development on Coursera. I downloaded the application to run my own dataset. It turns out to require more RAM. I tried it on the Google Colab which has 25GB RAM and it still doesn't work.

Another dataset that has 200 **64 * 64-pixel** images **can run perfectly**. My dataset has 500 **800 * 800** images and **crashes due to lack of RAM**. I think this is the problem. Now I have two questions:

1. How can I optimize this application to train my dataset?
2. Is there any chance to have a better NN model to solve the RAM question?

```
    # GRADED FUNCTION: two_layer_model
    def two_layer_model(X, Y, layers_dims, learning_rate = 0.0075, num_iterations = 3000, print_cost=False):
        """
        Implements a two-layer neural network: LINEAR->RELU->LINEAR->SIGMOID.
        
        Arguments:
        X -- input data, of shape (n_x, number of examples)
        Y -- true "label" vector (containing 1 if cat, 0 if non-cat), of shape (1, number of examples)
        layers_dims -- dimensions of the layers (n_x, n_h, n_y)
        num_iterations -- number of iterations of the optimization loop
        learning_rate -- learning rate of the gradient descent update rule
        print_cost -- If set to True, this will print the cost every 100 iterations 
        
        Returns:
        parameters -- a dictionary containing W1, W2, b1, and b2
        """
        
        np.random.seed(1)
        grads = {}
        costs = []                              # to keep track of the cost
        m = X.shape[1]                           # number of examples
        (n_x, n_h, n_y) = layers_dims
        
        # Initialize parameters dictionary, by calling one of the functions you'd previously implemented
        ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
        parameters = initialize_parameters(n_x, n_h, n_y)
        ### END CODE HERE ###
        
        # Get W1, b1, W2 and b2 from the dictionary parameters.
        W1 = parameters["W1"]
        b1 = parameters["b1"]
        W2 = parameters["W2"]
        b2 = parameters["b2"]
        
        # Loop (gradient descent)
    
        for i in range(0, num_iterations):
    
            # Forward propagation: LINEAR -> RELU -> LINEAR -> SIGMOID. Inputs: "X, W1, b1, W2, b2". Output: "A1, cache1, A2, cache2".
            ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
            A1, cache1 = linear_activation_forward(X, W1, b1, activation='relu')
            A2, cache2 = linear_activation_forward(A1, W2, b2, activation='sigmoid')
            ### END CODE HERE ###
            
            # Compute cost
            ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 1 line of code)
            cost = compute_cost(A2, Y)
            ### END CODE HERE ###
            
            # Initializing backward propagation
            dA2 = - (np.divide(Y, A2) - np.divide(1 - Y, 1 - A2))
            
            # Backward propagation. Inputs: "dA2, cache2, cache1". Outputs: "dA1, dW2, db2; also dA0 (not used), dW1, db1".
            ### START CODE HERE ### (≈ 2 lines of code)
            dA1, dW2, db2 =  linear_activation_backward(dA2, cache2, activation='sigmoid')
            dA0, dW1, db1 =  linear_activation_backward(dA1, cache1, activation='relu')
            ### END CODE HERE ###
            
            # Set grads['dWl'] to dW1, grads['db1'] to db1, grads['dW2'] to dW2, grads['db2'] to db2
            grads['dW1'] = dW1
            grads['db1'] = db1
            grads['dW2'] = dW2
            grads['db2'] = db2
            
            # Update parameters.
            ### START CODE HERE ### (approx. 1 line of code)
            parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
            ### END CODE HERE ###
    
            # Retrieve W1, b1, W2, b2 from parameters
            W1 = parameters["W1"]
            b1 = parameters["b1"]
            W2 = parameters["W2"]
            b2 = parameters["b2"]
            
            # Print the cost every 100 training example
            if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
                print("Cost after iteration {}: {}".format(i, np.squeeze(cost)))
            if print_cost and i % 100 == 0:
                costs.append(cost)
           
        # plot the cost
    
        plt.plot(np.squeeze(costs))
        plt.ylabel('cost')
        plt.xlabel('iterations (per tens)')
        plt.title("Learning rate =" + str(learning_rate))
        plt.show()
        
        return parameters
```

This method is the main method to train my dataset.
After running this statement:

```
parameters = two_layer_model(train_x, train_y, layers_dims = (n_x, n_h, n_y), num_iterations = 2500, print_cost=True)
```

I excepted to get the output like as follows:

```
Cost after iteration 100: 0.6464320953428849
Cost after iteration 200: 0.6325140647912678
Cost after iteration 300: 0.6015024920354665
Cost after iteration 400: 0.5601966311605747
Cost after iteration 500: 0.5158304772764729
Cost after iteration 600: 0.4754901313943325
Cost after iteration 700: 0.43391631512257495
Cost after iteration 800: 0.4007977536203887
Cost after iteration 900: 0.35807050113237976
Cost after iteration 1000: 0.33942815383664127
Cost after iteration 1100: 0.30527536361962654
Cost after iteration 1200: 0.2749137728213016
Cost after iteration 1300: 0.24681768210614846
Cost after iteration 1400: 0.19850735037466097
Cost after iteration 1500: 0.17448318112556657
Cost after iteration 1600: 0.1708076297809689
Cost after iteration 1700: 0.11306524562164715
Cost after iteration 1800: 0.09629426845937145
Cost after iteration 1900: 0.08342617959726863
Cost after iteration 2000: 0.07439078704319078
Cost after iteration 2100: 0.06630748132267933
Cost after iteration 2200: 0.0591932950103817
Cost after iteration 2300: 0.05336140348560554
Cost after iteration 2400: 0.04855478562877016
```

But my application **crashed after the first line calculated** cost after iteration 100, here is the app log from Colab:

| Timestamp | Level | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Feb 6, 2021, 6:31:31 PM | WARNING | WARNING:root:kernel 88a81184-be18-4889-9d35-6fccdf6f1aa6 restarted |
| Feb 6, 2021, 6:31:31 PM | INFO | KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports |
| Feb 6, 2021, 6:31:25 PM | WARNING | tcmalloc: large alloc 7925760000 bytes == 0x5f3bd8000 @ 0x7fd3aaaa81e7 0x7fd3a1fa741e 0x7fd3a1ff7c2b 0x7fd3a1ff8240 0x7fd3a1ff039a 0x7fd3a22170a5 0x7fd3a2095928 0x7fd3a209985d 0x566f73 0x59fd0e 0x7fd3a1fe4ea7 0x50a12f 0x50beb4 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd 0x50beb4 0x5095c8 0x50a2fd 0x50beb4 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd 0x50cc96 0x507be4 0x509900 0x50a2fd 0x50cc96 0x507be4 0x5161c5 0x50a12f |

**The whole application code can be found** [here](https://github.com/Kulbear/deep-learning-coursera/blob/master/Neural%20Networks%20and%20Deep%20Learning/Deep%20Neural%20Network%20-%20Application.ipynb)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not try analyzing one image at a time? If the library doesn't do it efficiently enough (by using all available cores), use another library.

Comment: Look at the concept of mini-batch. Loading the full data set in memory is not scalable in deep learning applications. Also, your choice of model should not be driven by the RAM space it takes but by the problem that you are trying to solve and by your experimental results. Never change a model just so that you can fit more images in memory, this strategy does not make sense. Also, this is not the right SE site for this question imo..